# gitignore matching character repetitions

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a directory in a git repository with some files in it, let's call it `matchdir`:

```
$ ls matchdir
2fd4e1c67a2d28fced849ee1bb76e7391b93eb12
da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709
file.py
someotherfile.txt
```

I want to add the files that match 40 hex characters to my `.gitignore` file. Something like `matchdir/[0-9a-f]{32}` but that doesn't seem to work. Is there any way to match a specific number of repetitions of a character in a .gitignore file?

Comment: out of curiosity, why have you files that are named as a sha1-chksum? `gitignore(5)` and `fnmatch(3)` says that what you are trying to do is not possible.

Comment: The repository is a web server that does some processing and needs a working directory. Ideally, I'd change the working directory to be in a subdir and match that instead, but I can't change that right now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
matchdir/????????????????????????????????????????
```

Will match all files with exactly 40 letters.  That's not only hex letters, but it's better than `matchdir/*` that will match any length.  Typing the 40 `?` takes only 3 keystrokes under emacs: <kbd>C-4</kbd><kbd>C-0</kbd><kbd>?</kbd>.

It's now easy to search and replace `?` by `[0-9a-f]` if you want to catch only hex numbers:

```
matchdir/[0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f]
```

Comment: Not pretty, but I like it. This answers the original question more accurately, so I've accepted it.

Comment: Haha, classical UBE - Ugly But Effective. +1

Answer (score 2):

Not an exact match, but if those are the only files without an extension and there are no subdirectories, a workaround might be this:

```
matchdir/*
!matchdir/*.*
```

Ignore all files, then unignore those with a dot.

Comment: Nice suggestion but it won't work for me, as there are some other files without an extension.

Comment: @jterrace - if the "other" files without an extension are limited, can't you just list them as `!files`?

Comment: I ended up using a modified version of this. Thanks @Thilo and @Fredrik